# What is this golden sword?

Tags: king-of-avalon-dragon-warfare

I've noticed the following golden sword during KvK. Screenshot below:

[image: King of Avalon, golden sword]

[image: King of Avalon, golden sword]

Upon inspection, it doesn't show any name as usual. It's not the temp relic, as you can have only one (which is shown with the countdown), and also doesn't look like a kingdom buff. What is this sword called and how you can get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excalibur. King lifts Excalibur after the battle and that's it. If you look at the statue in the centre of forest you can see it holding that sword as well.